# maven: how to disable certain dependencies?

Tags: java, maven

Well, I'm not talking about the well-known commons-logging problem, I know I can disable it by setting the 99.0-does-not-exist version.

My problems is, some packages are contained in different dependencies, say, aspectjlib is contained both in org.aspectj:aspectjlib and aspectj:aspectjlib. In some cases, transitive dependencies may introduce the two jars at the same time, while of different versions, e.g., org.aspectj:aspectjlib:1.7.3, aspectj:aspectjlib:1.6.1. And mis-loading aspectj:aspectjlib:1.6.1 accidentally is not my intention. So is there a way like commons-logging that I can disable aspectj:aspectjlib completely?

I tried the same trick using 99.0-does-not-exist, only to find an error from maven:

---

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXX: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project XXX:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following
>   artifacts could not be resolved:
>   aspectj:aspectjlib:jar:99.0-does-not-exist,
>   aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:99.0-does-not-exist,
>   aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:99.0-does-not-exist: Could not find artifact
>   aspectj:aspectjlib:jar:99.0-does-not-exist in tbmirror
>   (http://mvnrepo.taobao.ali.com/mvn/repository) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although some repositories do provide 99.0-does-not-exist for logging system dependencies like log4j, slf4j-log4j, commons-logging, etc., this is not a universal solution.

I find a solution to do this: use 'provided' scope.
To clarify, in my example above, I have two conflicting dependencies: org.aspectj:aspectjlib:1.7.3, aspectj:aspectjlib:1.6.1, I want to disable aspectj:aspectjlib:1.6.1, I only need to put this in top-level pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjlib</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

in this way, aspectj:aspectjlib:1.6.1 will never appear in the final built lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven's [dependency exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions) to eliminate the version you don't want.  Using your example:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>includes-new-aspectj</groupId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>includes-old-aspectj</groupId>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.aspectj<groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjlib</artifactId>
      <exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Alternatively, you can simply pin the version you desire using [dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management):

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjlib</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>includes-new-aspectj</groupId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>includes-old-aspectj</groupId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you are not sure which dependencies include which versions, you can use this to discover that info:

```bash
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes='org.aspectj:aspectjlib'
```

Answer (score -1):

[There is no](http://central.maven.org/maven2/aspectj/aspectjlib/) `99.0` version for `aspectj:aspectjlib`, your project is configured to use wrong version, check for `99.0` in your `pom.xml`

Comment: Yes I know the version does not exist, my intention is to set a non-exist version, so that maven will find an empty dependency like commos-logging does, and apparently this does not work.

Comment: if it fails to resolve dependency it will fail, why you need an empty jar in your classpath anyways ?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, two aspectjlib jars exist with different versions, I need to exclude aspectj:aspectjlib:1.6.1, and finding all transitive dependencies that use aspectj:aspectjlib:1.6.1 and exclude them separately is quite some work, I think a better way would be add a non-exist version at the top-level pom.

Comment: did oyu try `mvn dependency:tree` ?

Comment: Yes, I know this can sort out all dependencies, but if 30 of my dependencies use aspectjlib transitively, I'll have to exclude them 30 times in my pom, it will be a mess.

Comment: Your approach is a hack to fix this issue, better to make use of optional and/or exclusions tags